# ERROR: The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Function calls a stored procedure:

[image]

Stored procedure: the condition entered in else and `exec stp_createnewsoal_new`.

All parameters exist.

[image]

Error:

Why do I get an error like this? If I exec manually `stp_createnewsoal_new` in database (I get from provider), `stp_createnewsoal_new` can insert data into the table. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: Include `stp_createnewsoal_new` content to be checked later, probably related with output parameter on that SP (try setting the return type to `None` instead of certain data type).